# Selenium - Save website including all images, css, dom

Tags: java, dom, selenium, save

I would like to visit a page with selenium using firefox or chrome. When the page is loaded I would like to download all images, css, dom from the page.

I would like to store every image like I find them in:

```
chrome -> Tools->Development Tools -> Resources -> Images
```

Is it possible to get access via selenium and save everything?

So far I only found this page, which has no interesting hints for me:
http://ldanswers.org/wordpress/zisser/2014/11/24/save-whole-web-page-with-all-resources-in-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: I think [jaunt](http://jaunt-api.com/) can do this if you can't get it working with selenium

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem by myself. The Problem is when you click on Save page as -> STRG + S an OS-Window pops up, which can't be managed by Selenium. I read about many possible solutions about that using tools like AutoIT, xnee, jna or Java Robot.

I didn't wanted to use such tools. So I searched for a firefox addon which is able to download a whole page (including images, css, html). After some seconds I found [Scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/scrapbook/).

At last I downloaded the Addon File scrapbook-1.5.11-fx.xpi, modified some values in it and used it with selenium. It is working very vell.

Values I changed at **/defaults/preferences/scrapbook-prefs.js** which is

```
pref("scrapbook.data.default", false);
pref("scrapbook.data.path", "/Path/to/store/webpage");
pref("scrapbook.key.save", "D");
```

This config tells scrapbook to save the webpages at the defined path and that the shortcut for saving a page is **STRG + SHIFT + D**.

Now you only have to add the Plugin to the firefox profile,call a website and Send the shortcut to the browser.

```
FirefoxProfile oProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        File extension = new File("scrapbook-1.5.11-fx.xpi");
        try {
            oProfile.addExtension(extension);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(oProfile);
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.SHIFT, "D")).perform();
```

I hope this helps someone!

Edit: If you want scrapbook to also save JavaScript per Default you have to change the file saver.js in the Plugin and set the value "script" : false  to true.

Comment: This plugin doesn't work with Firefox Quantum and Tor Browser. I've found another plugin that allows to do this and is [SavePage WE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-page-we/). You can set your shortcut but, sigh, will show a popup for downloading the page. 

In the settings, I've allowed to automatically download content. **It has to be used consciously because may represent a security risk.**