# How to save a file in current working directory with pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui, getcwd

I'm trying to save a webpage through `selenium` and "ctrl+s" via `pyautogui`. But I couldn't change the directory for saving when the save file window comes. The examples I could find about it are to save the screenshot in a specified directory. However, I'd like to save exactly in the current working directory, in case it may need to work in other computers.

```
page = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
page = page.get(url)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
time.sleep(3)
path = os.getcwd()
pyautogui.typewrite('foo' + '.html')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Is it possible to insert `os.getcwd()` somewhere in this code? I tried to add `os.getcwd()` at some places(such as `(path + 'foo' + '.html')`) but it didn't work, as expected. Or is there any other way to do?

Comment: is there a point in using pyautogui for this? selenium lets you access `page_source` which you can then save in whatever path you want.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with selenium either. I tried several ways to save webpage but the statics created problem. As a result I ended up [here]: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53966809/5619835)

As the comment suggest there, I could change the directory after saving the file, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it in a short way, before saving the file. @Chase

Answer (score 0):

you could just let pyautogui type the folder path and the file name directly before key "Enter" has been pressed. However that path needs to be exist at the first place.

There are other way of doing it, since selenium already retrieved the web elements.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35408235)