# Storing selenium driver pages when run test to improve performance

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest, vcr, cassette

I was using an internal API to get the data from a website and I stored this requests using a VCR(cassette), but this API is no longer available.

Therefore, I'm using Selenium to handle pages and scrap the data that I need, but, to improve the performance, I would to store the pages that the webdriver travel, such as I was doing with simple requests, I mean, store this pages(such as requests) in the cassette VCR or something like it.

I think to download some page that the crawler travel and inject it in driver when run the unitttests, but maybe it's possible to configure the VCR to do something like it(and it's more simple).

It's possible to do it?

Comment: yes it is.......

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I have not encountered how to do it(i searched in vcr/unittest/selenium docs). Can you post an example? In this case, I would to use only VCR to store the pages travelled by selenium(if possible), instead of I store It manually and inject

Comment: you could use this [tool](http://www.httrack.com/) to download the page

Comment: or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63573072/6651840) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53966809/6651840)